# SQL Server Management Studio Express and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ssms

Is there a way to use SQL Server Management Studio Express together with a MySQL database? I guess even if it works, intellisense wont work?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this tool for MySQL - http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/, try Express (Code Completion/Intellisense is partially suported - restricted to server-side objects only) or Trial version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will not works with MySQL.The name of product is "SQL Server Management Studio", so it manages SQL Server instances.

If you need tool with similar functionality, try Toad for MySQL, it's freeware or Oracle SQLDeveloper.

Comment: The name of the product is actually "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio" despite the acronym being SSMS.  SQL means "Standardized Query Language".  I wish more aspects of SQL were standard like the `LIMIT` command!  But, that's not relevant at all here.

Comment: Just for the record, "SQL" actually stands for "Structured Query Language"

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you found the answer yet, but the following links can help:
1- [HOWTO: Setup SQL Server Linked Server to MySQL](http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/25/howto-setup-sql-server-linked-server-to-mysql/)
2- [Creating Linked server to MYSQL from SQL Server](http://sql-articles.com/articles/dba/creating-linked-server-to-mysql-from-sql-server/)

Answer (score 2):

I can't see how this will ever work, SSMS is written only for MSSQL.

You can however create a link server to the mysql database and use it that way, I doubt intellisense will work though. see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/163610/anyway-to-use-ssms-to-connect-to-mysql) for more info.

Comment: Yes, but you still need to manage existing SQL Server.Even when you connect ODBC linked database, you lose MySQL specific functinality, you will be limited by ODBC compatible features

Comment: you are correct, sql express will do fine however so that should not be an issue but this is the only way I can think of that it will be possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

I think this answer needs to be updated and as we now live in a Cloud world I have created a proof of concept for you, fellas.

1. Download MySQL ODBC driver: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/ and install
2. Go to ODBC Data Source Administrator > User DNS > Add..., and fill all the fields wit the right informations. Then test if the connections works
   [image]
3. Go to ODBC Data Source Administrator > System DNS > Add..., and fill all the fields wit the right informations. Then test if the connections works
   [image]
4. In SSMS go to Server Objects > Linked Servers > New Linked Server...
   [image]
5. Under General set

   - Linked server: (Put what you want, I put the name of the server for simplicity)
   - Provider: **Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers**
   - Product name: (Put what you want, I put the name of the server for simplicity, you might want to put MySQL)
   - Data source: **Must have the same name as the System Data Source's Name**
     [image]
6. Under Security select "Be made using this security context" and enter you user and password for remote login to MySQL
   [image]
7. Under Server Options set RPC and RPC Out as True
   [image]
8. Go to Server Objects > Linked Servers > Providers > MSDASQL, and enable: Nested queries, Level zero only, Allow inprocess, Supports 'Like' operator
   [image]
9. Restart SQL Server and SQL Server Agent
10. You can now query MySQL from SSMS using this structure:

    select * from OPENQUERY(linked_server_name, 'SELECT * FROM database_name.table_name')

or simply:

```
SELECT * FROM linked_server_name...table_name
```

[image]